# react-redux connect should have side effects?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a component which need logged-in user data but in this component I'm not sure if user is logged in yet or not
is it a bad practice to check existance data in mapStateToProps and redirect to login page if needed? is it a side effect?
what about fetching data which is nit exist in state yet? 
how should I handle such problems?

what should we do in mapState and what we shouldn't do?
is there any good practice for it?

Comment: You should provide us with the codebase that you are working with because your question is bordering on opinion-based and being too broad, but I will provide an answer below making certain assumptions due to lack of information on your part.

Answer (score 0):

> it a bad practice to check existance data in mapStateToProps and redirect to login page if needed?

I am not sure of whether it's a best practice or not, but if we look at the semantics of [`mapStateToProps`](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments), it's main usage is mapping redux state to component props.

So in that sense anything that is not mapping can be considered a side-effect.

If you want to align with redux-way then you pass down with `mapStateToProps` properties that you want to react to, and you change those properties with `mapDispatchToProps`.

So in your case you would have some sort of `Authentication` service, that would have methods like `login`, `logout`, `register`, which would dispatch actions to your redux `store`, and in `mapStateToProps` you would subscribe to something like `isAuthenticated`.

And in your render you would check if `this.props.isAuthenticated ? <PrintSome> : null`

You can also check this tutorial with basically same idea, but taken out into a higher order component for reusability https://medium.com/quick-code/adding-authentication-to-react-redux-firebase-app-f0efcb1c519a

Comment: thanks for your answer.
i had read your suggested articles but I had not understand who should handling of redirect to `/login` ?

Comment: @MHA15 https://medium.com/quick-code/adding-authentication-to-react-redux-firebase-app-f0efcb1c519a#132b line 13 in the code sample

Answer (score 0):

So let's assume you have defined your routes in the `src/components/App.js` component. You are at a point where you need to ensure that your `App` component knows whether or not the user is actually signed in at all.

Let's also assume that you have already developed a reducer in `reducers/auth.js` to record whether a user is signed in or not and you have assigned the `authReducer` to your `auth` piece of state.

At this point, inside your `src/components/App.js` file you would need to import:

`import { connect } from 'react-redux';`

Then at the bottom of your `App` component you need to define your `mapStateToProps` like so:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { auth: state.auth }
}

export default App;
```

So what I am recommending above is that you pass `state` to `mapStateToProps` and then `return` an object with a key of `auth` and that will take whatever value is coming out of the `authReducer`.

Then you take the `connect()` function you imported and pass `mapStateToProps` to it like so:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);`

So now your `App` component knows whether or not the user is signed in.

So what is an advantage of implementing the above? Well, it gives you the flexibility of determining what to display in your view depending on whether the user is signed in or not. For example, a sign-in/sign-out button.

You can now develop that button with a helper method that has a conditional like so:

```
renderButton() {
  if (this.props.auth) {
   return (
     <button>
       Sign Out
     </button>
   );
  } else {
   return (
     <button>
       Sign In
     </button>
   );
  }
}
```